# Limit Notation: $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) =\infty $ or $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: limits, notation

If $f(x) \to \infty $ as $x \to \infty $,

Which of the following statements would be more correct:

$I.$ $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) =\infty $$

Or

$II. $ $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \rightarrow  \infty $$

I thought $II$ would be more appropriate?

Comment: The second one is incorrect. The left hand side of the symbol $\to$ has to be a function or sequence or something else with a free variable that can be made to tend towards something. Here, the left hand side is just a constant. However, you could have something like

$$\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 {m^n}\right)\xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{} 0$$

Comment: The nomenclature of the term "limit" implies the arrow you're drawing there. As $x \rightarrow \infty$, $f(x) \rightarrow 0$, but the *limit* means "what is $f(x)$ *limited* by as $x \rightarrow \infty$?" There are rigorous mathematical definitions of a limit, and that is not one of them, but the semantics accurately imply the notation in a way that's easy to remember.

Comment: The limit can't "go" anywhere. It is a fixed number (or infinity)

Answer (score 26):

You have two usual notations :

$$(1)\qquad \lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$$

and

$$(2)\qquad f(x)\xrightarrow[x\to+\infty]{}+\infty.$$

So in your case, the first one is correct.

(The second one is not appropriate because $\to$ usually means *tends to*, and a limit is *equal to* something.)

Comment: The limit is not "equal to" infinity. In the common formalism, infinity is not a number. So increasing or decreasing without bound means the limit does not exist, but we use a shorthand of saying the limit is infinity to indicate whether it increases or decreases. Given that, how is it incorrect to say that it tends to infinity? That sounds more correct to me, since it can't be equal. Even if you're correct about the notation, I believe your explanation has severe problems.

Comment: jpmc26, f(x) "tends to" infinity, but lim f(x) is equal to infinity.

Comment: @jpmc26 I agree with MikeBenfield. I will add that even if it is not rigorous, it's a nice way to see in your mind $f(x)$ *tending* to something, and $\lim f(x)$ being *equal* to something.

Comment: @E.Joseph Having mnemonics is fine, but on a math site where people come here asking questions because they're confused about something, we should make it *very* clear what is rigorous and what is just a memory aid.

Comment: @jpmc26 It is not entirely unrigorous to write $\lim f(x)=\infty$, if you really don't want to think of it as a mnemonic then think of it as an element of an extended real number system (by two points compactification) which is completely rigorous.

Comment: @BigbearZzz I explicitly acknowledged the existence of extended number systems, but these are *not* the number systems we typically use. Certainly not at the level where you're still learning the notation of limits. To claim it is "equal" without explicitly declaring that you're using an out of the ordinary extended number system is misleading at best. We *must* distinguish between notation and concept; otherwise you get into the kind of trouble where people think $ \frac{dy}{dx} $ is division!

Comment: @jpmc26 I don't see any real problem about teaching a freshman extended real in his/her first course in calculus. Just imagining a line to be augmented by two quantities whose behavior agree pretty well with what you'd expect $\infty,-\infty$ to do doesn't sound challenging to me. This would be beneficial as well since it both aids intuition and is useful in higher mathematics. I fully support the point that the teacher should explicitly mention that infinitely is not a real number though.

Comment: By the way, I am pretty sure that you must have seen the big O notation. That is on the whole different level of potentially misleading notation but I rarely see any one object to that. On the other hand, saying that limit is _equal to_ infinity doesn't lead to any real problem at all. A notations that leads to correct result even when it is "misused" reflect the fact that the intuition behind it is very strong. Discouraging people from saying "the limit is infinity" does more harm than good in my opinion.

Comment: @BigbearZzz If you think I was trying to make a case against the notation or that phrasing, you have misunderstood. I merely called for clarity.

Answer (score 10):

First one is correct; "→" generally means "tend(s) to".  Limits either equal something (or +/- inf) or don't exist; they do not tend to something.

Comment: "Limits equal something." Limits often don't exist. In fact, increasing or decreasing without bound is considered an example of a limit not existing, since infinity is not a number (in the common formalism). So not all limits "equal something."

Comment: @jpmc26 you confuse "the limit exists" and "the limit exists and is finite". It is useful to distinguish no limiting behavior (e.g. oscillation) from unbounded growing in a given direction ($+\infty$, $-\infty$, or even some directed infinity).

Answer (score 9):

The first one is correct, the second one is incorrect.